# Проблемы с вызовом контекстного меню

Tags: android

У меня есть два слушателя для `ListView`:

```
lvMain.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.i(TAG, MSG + "короткое нажатие: " + arrayOfDictionaries[position]);

            TextView textView_2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.choice_dictionary_textView_2);

            registerForContextMenu(textView_2);
            openContextMenu(textView_2);

            return;
        }
    });
```

и

```
   lvMain.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.i(TAG, MSG + "длинное нажатие 1: " + arrayOfDictionaries[position]);


            TextView textView_2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.choice_dictionary_textView_2);

            registerForContextMenu(textView_2);
            openContextMenu(textView_2);

            Log.i(TAG, MSG + "длинное нажатие 2: " + arrayOfDictionaries[position]);

            return false;
        }
    });
```

При вызове первого слушателя, код работает и контекстное меню вызывается, а при работе второго — нет! Как это можно исправить и почему это происходит?

Вот код контекстного меню:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, "Удалить");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 2, Menu.NONE, "Изменить");
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте из второго возвращать `true`.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, завтра попробую. Встал из-за компьютера, а AIDE компилирует с ошибкой и не могу посмотреть логи.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, заработало! Но... Почему? Что изменилось? И добавьте это в ответ.

Comment: Ответ с пояснениями добавил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем коде `onItemLongClick` должен возвращать `true`, т.к. согласно документации возвращаемое значение метода определяет будет ли дальше передаваться событие долгого нажатия. Возвращая `false` вы препятствуете дальнейшей обработке долгого нажатия и поэтому контекстное меню не вызывается.

Answer (score 1):

Контексное меню не надо регистрировать в OnItemLongClickListener. Вот тебе рабочий пример реализованный в ListFragment. По аналогии делай у себя. И при долгом нажатии на item у тебя будет появляться контексное меню.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(getAdapter());
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);
    menu.add(0, R.string.item_show, 0, getString(R.string.item_show));
    menu.add(0, R.string.item_export, 0, getString(R.string.item_export));
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    int position = info.position;
    YourObject obj = (YourObject) getAdapter().getItem(position);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.string.item_show:
            //TODO
            break;
        case R.string.item_export:
            //TODO
            break;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Хм... Сейчас попробую.

Comment: А как "подсоединить" этот ``ListFragment`` к ``ListView``?  И почему у Вас ``@Nullable Bundle``, а не ``Bundle``? И от куда Вы выхватываете адаптер через "getAdapter()", у меня выдает ошибку? И что за ``YourObject``?

Comment: ListFragment это спец. фрагмент в который уже встроенн ListView. Он идеально подойдёт если во фрагменте ничего не будет кроме ListView. в него уже встроенны методы getListView() и getListAdapter(). Почитай тут(http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v4/app/ListFragment.html). 
@Nullable - аннотация.
YourObject замени на свой объект, помойму это очевидно.

Comment: А вообще вместо getAdapter и getListView вствляй свои данные, я же не знаю какие они у тебя.

Comment: То есть, вместо ``getAdapter()``, нужно прописать ``CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(ChoiceDictionary.this, R.layout.custom_list_adapter, Arrays.asList(arrayOfDictionaries));``, а вместо ``YourObject`` что? Я не использую никаких объектов!

Comment: Вот весь мой код для ``ListView``: ``ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.choice_dictionary_listView_1);
        CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(ChoiceDictionary.this, R.layout.custom_list_adapter, Arrays.asList(arrayOfDictionaries));
        lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);``

Comment: Но у Вас есть одно но. Вызов контекстного меню произойдет, но перед ним произойдет вызов ``onItemClickListener`` или он не произойдет вовсе. По крайней мере, код говорит о этом...